# ' or " in PHP's Postgres queries

Tags: php, postgresql

1. **When should you use the character ' in PHP pg queries?**
2. **When should you use the character " in PHP pg queries?**

This question is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350883/checking-return-value-of-pgqueryparams-by-php/1350891#1350891).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Into a PostgreSQL query, you must use '

When you build a query in PHP, you may use ' or "

```
"select * from table where id = 'me'"
```

or

```
'select * from table where id = \'me\''
```

Comment: @Masi: #1 is correct -- do not put query parameters in quotes.

Comment: @Luc M: You can use " in PostgreSQL query, but it applies to delimited identifiers, instead of string literals.

Answer (score 4):

String literals in Postgres are defined using single quotes.  Double quotes are used around identifiers. So the following query is valid.

```
SELECT "id", "name" FROM my_table WHERE "name" = 'Brian'
```

However, judging by the answer that you linked to, you're asking about single quote ' vs double quote " in PHP strings, rather than postgres queries.

The same as normal strings, a string in double quotes will interpolate variables, while a string in single quotes will have exactly what you put in.

```
$my_var = "noob";

echo "This is a test string, $my_var\nGot it?";
>> This is a test string, noob
>> Got it?

echo 'This is a test string, $my_var\nGot it?';
>> This is a test string, $my_var\nGot it?
```

Comment: I am not sure whether your examples apply in the PHP pg queries, since they are in different environments that is not inside a query. Your answer also conflicts with Vitaly's answer.